# the celebrations of the connections of a horse

Tags: vocabulary

> The deaths of two of yesterday's Melbourne Cup runners put a dampener on the celebrations of the **connections** of the resounding winner, the German stayer Protectionist. 
>   And it reignited calls from animal welfare activists to tighten racing's rules and ban whipping.
>   While seven year old stallion Araldo broke a leg after being spooked while returning to the mounting yard, an initial autopsy has revealed that Japanese horse Admire Rakti died from a heart attack, but what caused it might be more difficult to establish, as Samantha Donovan reports. ([Aussie ABC](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2014/s4121677.htm))

I can't find the meaning of 'connections' that makes sense. What does it mean?

Comment: Contacts, friends, acquaintances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It certainly looks odd.  However a bit of digging reveals this definition from Wikipedia:

> **Connections**.
>       The owner and trainer of a horse. The term can also be extended to other members of a racing team or partnership. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_horse_racing_terminology)